# openSIPS setup an onreply route if the call is picked up

Tags: sip, voip, opensips

I'm wondering if is it possible to set a condition for call answered/picked up in an onreply_route

something like this

```
onreply_route {
 if(call picked up) {
  xlog("ON AIR");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways in which you can achieve this. For your case, I would use the `tm` module's `t_check_status()` function:

```
onreply_route {
    if (t_check_status("2[0-9][0-9]")) {
        xlog("ON AIR");
    }
}
```

However, note that this will not work if your SIP proxy is stateless (i.e. if you don't use `tm` at all)! In this case, we would need to access the information in a more low-level way, by reading it straight off the received message using the `$rs` variable (*SIP reply status*):

```
onreply_route {
    if ($rs == 200) { # or ($rs =~ "2[0-9][0-9]")
        xlog("ON AIR");
    }
}
```